# How can I get a bigquery table's clustering information

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a generalized code to automate load jobs for multiple tables.

Of the tables i'm trying to automate load jobs for, one of the table is clustered and i'm getting the following error : `"Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day) clustering(zipcode,address), but input partitioning specification is interval(type:day)"`

Here is the code where I'm trying to load tables:
My question is, given the tableId and assuming that the table already exists, how can I get Clustering information of the table to set it as a part of `loadConfig.setClustering(clustering)`

```java
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    TableId tableId =
        TableId.of(
           FLAG_project.get(),
           FLAG_dataset_name.get(),
           FLAG_table_name.get());

    TimePartitioning partitioning = TimePartitioning.of(TimePartitioning.Type.DAY);
    
    CsvOptions csvOptions = CsvOptions.newBuilder().setAllowJaggedRows(true).build();

    LoadJobConfiguration loadConfig =
        LoadJobConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId, sourceUri, csvOptions)
            .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.csv())
            .setTimePartitioning(partitioning)
            .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .setAutodetect(false)
            .setMaxBadRecords(1000)
            .setIgnoreUnknownValues(true)
            .build();

    Job loadJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(loadConfig));
    loadJob = loadJob.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options, partitioning and clustering are meant to be used when you're creating a table, for example, if you're loading data and want to create the table if it doesn't exist.

If you're exclusively loading data into tables that already exist, then my recommendation would be to avoid altogether the specification of the partitioning and clustering options as it is not really needed.

Finally, if you want the clustering information for a table, here's an example on how to do it:

```java
// Get the tableId
TableId tableId = TableId.of(projectId, datasetName, tableName);

// Get the table
Table table = bigquery.getTable(tableId);

// Get the definition   
StandardTableDefinition tableDefinition = table.getDefinition();

// Get the clustering information
Clustering clustering = tableDefinition.getClustering();
```

Now you can use it to create in your configuration

```java
.setClustering(clustering)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson projectName:datasetName.tableName | jq '.clustering.fields[]'
```

**Example:**

```
bq show --format=prettyjson fh-bigquery:wikipedia_v3.pageviews_2017 | jq '.clustering.fields[]'
```

**Output:**

```
"wiki"
"title"
```

Comment: Are they sorted by clustering order or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    client = bigquery.Client(project="PROJECT_ID")
    table = client.get_table("PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLE")
    print(table.clustering_fields)
```